# How to undo recent driver upgrades

Tags: drivers, apt, mouse

My mouse is behaving very strange. Everything works fine until I press CTRL then it behaves like mouse wheel up is pressed.

In firefox I can surf normally, but as soon as I press CTRL page starts zooming in. I thought this was firefox issue, but I can't even use ALT+TAB anymore because list keeps shifting, as if mouse wheel up is pressed.

I have updated drivers 3 days ago, but I think I have rebooted only recently.

```
grep driver /var/log/dpkg.log
2016-11-21 07:34:38 upgrade ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17linuxmint1 1:0.4.17.2linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:38 status half-configured ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:38 status unpacked ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:38 status half-installed ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:38 status half-installed ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:38 status unpacked ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17.2linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:38 status unpacked ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17.2linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:50 configure ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17.2linuxmint1 <none>
2016-11-21 07:34:50 status unpacked ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17.2linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:50 status unpacked ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17.2linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:50 status half-configured ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17.2linuxmint1
2016-11-21 07:34:51 status installed ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.17.2linuxmint1
```

How to find out old version of `ubuntu-drivers-common` and revert back to it?